# Can't understand v.emplace_back lambda block

Tags: c++, vector, boost

Can someone explain what's happening inside the `v.emplace_back` block? `v` holds `std::thread`, but neither `net::io_context` "is a" `std::thread` nor `ioc->run()` returns a `std::thread`. In general what's happening inside the lambda block?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        std::cerr <<
            "Usage: http-server-async <address> <port> <doc_root> <threads>\n" <<
            "Example:\n" <<
            "    http-server-async 0.0.0.0 8080 . 1\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto const address = net::ip::make_address(argv[1]);
    auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi(argv[2]));
    auto const doc_root = std::make_shared<std::string>(argv[3]);
    auto const threads = std::max<int>(1, std::atoi(argv[4]));

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc{threads};

    // Create and launch a listening port
    std::make_shared<listener>(
        ioc,
        tcp::endpoint{address, port},
        doc_root)->run();

    // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    v.reserve(threads - 1);
    for(auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
        v.emplace_back(
        [&ioc]
        {
            ioc.run();
        });
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `emplace_back` passes arguments to the element constructor. The element is a `thread`.

Comment: It's using [overload 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) of `std::thread` constructor. You pass a function object (lambda) to the constructor of `std::thread` and that thread is emplaced in `std::vector`.

Comment: It should be answers but not comments.

Comment: @Nimrod why? I don't see the value in posting yet-another-documentation-style answer for `emplace` but this time with `std::vector` and `boost` tags. The goal of the site is to amass quality answers that can help many people, right. Commenters are just being helpful and mindful of their energy, IMO.

Comment: @sehe "*Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.*" I think the comment I pointed to is more like an answer but improvement. Aside, do you think "*documentation-style answer*" or *"documentation-style answer for duplicate questions (with different tags)"* has no value? I totally agree with you if latter. In many situations, askers just need some *documentation-style* answers with some explanation.  I started trying to assimilate into SO community just recently. So pls correct me if I'm somewhere wrong.

Comment: @Nimrod I don't think it's about right/wrong. It's about the goals and whether behaviour aligns, to me. I didn't see any wrong-doing. An answer that basically links to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back would be really poor as well, IMO.

Comment: @sehe Thanks. It makes some sense to me.